# Nested for loop for different variables in a dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop

I have the following

```
df
P M amount date
1 1 100    03/2012
1 1 200    04/2012
1 2 100    03/2012
1 2 200    04/2012
1 3 300    03/2012
1 4 400    03/2012
...
```

`unique(df$P)` and `unique(df$M)` return `[i] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`

I am trying to plot the amount vs. date (assuming the date is in POXIct) for every pair of P and M, so I have used a nested for loop for that.

```
for(i in unique(df$P)) {
for(j in unique(df$M)) {
    plot(amount ~ date, subset(df, P == i & M == j), 
         type = "l", main = print(paste("P", i, "and M", j)))
}
}
```

But then I got this error:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

And when I tried to do further functions, it turns out that for P = 1:4, each have 10 occurrence in M, i.e. Each P = 1 has M = 1:10

But when we reach P = 5, this only has only a single pair, with M = 2, and thus for loop is broken.

How can I modify my for loop to account for every pair?

Comment: Sorry but that didn't really solve it. The thing is, what expression do I use to limit my nested for loop to count only the M's under each P? Assuming that M is a list under P?

Answer (score 0):

2 edits: (1) make the unique M's a subset of the current P in the second `for` loop, and (2) only plot if you have sufficient data; I chose "sufficient to be ">2" data points, but use whatever works.

```
for(i in unique(df$P)) {
for(j in unique(df[df$P==i, "M")) {
    if(sum(df$P==i & df$M==j)>2) {
        plot(amount ~ date, subset(df, P == i & M == j), 
            type = "l", main = print(paste("P", i, "and M", j)))
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I found a different way of resolving it using piping with dplyr. Thank you though.